# Repeating Alarm Interval Offset

Tags: android, intervals, repeatingalarm

I'm trying to think through how I could do this, but I am coming up blank at the moment.

What I want to do is create the repeating alarm, but have the interval change every time it runs. I have another number, which will represent the number of milliseconds that the interval could differ from a default interval.

For example, lets say the default interval is 60000 milliseconds, or one minute. I have another number, which is 5000, and the alarm should trigger at a random point from 55000 milliseconds from the start to 65000 milliseconds from the start. Then, after it triggers, the alarm will reset as if it had triggered at 60000 milliseconds (not when it did with the offset).

The important thing to remember is that the alarm needs to have the default trigger time consistent. It should always trigger at the same interval without the offset.

I'm stumped. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: You can't do this with repeating alarms. You'll have to set them one at a time, i.e. receive the alarm and set the next one.

Comment: So...set a new alarm from the receiver of the previous alarm to send back to that same receiver?

Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Maybe reconsider using alarms, and instead use JobScheduler. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long) specifically, as I believe it might suit your needs, except maybe for the randomness. Another issue with this is that it is only supported in Lollipop and above.

Comment: @NuffsaidM8 Basically yes. After whatever work your receiver does, set up the next alarm. You can use extras in the alarm intent to pass some data to your future self (so to speak).